# When I run and Windows service in Azure, response time is extremely Poor

Tags: azure, windows-services

I run an application using Windows service running in the Windows server. This service contains all the business logic and access to SQL Server. It works well in a Normal PC as a server behind a Fixed IP router. Responses are in few seconds when accessed from clients over the Internet.

But when I install this service in Azure VM, Response is in two-three minutes. I am in Sri Lanka and the Azure data center is in US.

Comment: where is the sql server? did you move it to the cloud as well?

Comment: sqlserver is also in the VM

Answer (score 0):

Part of this is the latency between Sri Lanka and USA datacenter, but can also be due the size of the virtual machine you chose. Also, check if you're using SSD disks and new hardware (new series of virtual machine)

In case you are using SQL Database (Paas) take a look on the resources, you may need to scale it.

Comment: I do not think any cloud server can be less powerful than a PC which I use as a server for testing. I had a suspicion on the Data center location. I will try it on a Azure a data center in Sri Lanka, I think there is one by franchise operation, if you believe that this could be problem. Thanks Thiago

Comment: this is definitely one of them, but all the others I've mentioned can be a problem too. If you need, post the algorithm/code you're using. It can be the problem too.

Comment: code is too much to post and is copyrighted to the company I am working. Anyway thank you for your offer. Same SQL server I use in My server I am using in Cloud as well Thank Thiago for the Assistance I will post the results oncwe I am able to get it hosted Locally in Azure. It may taker some time